# "Invalid Window Handle" on exiting of WPF application that uses System.AddIn

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost, system.addin

I am working on a WPF application that is using System.AddIn to solve a memory leak issue we were having with a Windows Forms based control that was wrapped in a WindowsFormsHost control. The add-in is used to load and unload the Windows Forms based control as need to avoid the overhead of the WindowsFormsHost, which will hang around until application close in the current version of WPF and a memory leak in the Windows Forms based control due to bad cleanup logic.

The issue we are facing is that after loading and unloading the add-in in the application the WPF application will throw a Win32 exception of “Invalid Window Handle” on application exit. This would normally not be a terrible concern, however even though it is possible to catch the exception it does not stop Windows from seeing the application as crashed and showing a crash dialog under Windows 7 and this is unacceptable.

In regards to the code the relevant facts are:

1. The exception only occurs if the    add-in is loaded and unloaded by the    WPF host application. We are    disposing the WindowsFormsHost    control and the Windows Forms based    control in the add-in as part of a    custom Dispose method called prior to    unloading of the add-in.
2. The add-in is shutting down its    Dispatchers prior to unloading (as    part of the above disposal process)    which had been noted in MSDN    documentation and blog posts to be    required and to also solve this    problem which has not happened in    this case.
3. We have no choice in using the    Windows Forms based control as it is    required for some reporting, and    there are too many report files to    convert and no suitable WPF version    and no time to change it out.

I am not able to supply samples of the code so I am reaching out for any thoughts or previous experiences with such a scenario in case there is something I missed.

Comment: I've run into this as well - would love to hear an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue awhile back. I see that I call `Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown` (after testing that the control's content is not null) in my main window's `Window_Closing` event handler, and seem to recall that it was the solution.